# Second display is rotated

Tags: 12.10, multiple-monitors, display

I've just updated to Ubuntu 12.10 last night. When I was at the office, I connected my laptop with a projector. Although it can detect the projector, it incorrectly set the projector portrait. Also, if I click the *Rotation* dropdown, it had no *Normal* option. It only offered *Anticlockwise* and *Clockwise* options. Ofcourse the projector would display my desktop 90 degrees clockwise/anticlockwise.

I've just tested my laptop again with an LCD monitor, and it happened again. Below is my screenshot of my display settings dialog.

[image: portrait display]

My display adapter is Intel GMA 950.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

From [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149025/dual-monitor-second-screen-is-rotated-ubuntu-12-04-precise?rq=1), I tried

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1366x768 --rotate normal
```

This command can force the display to rotate the screen back to normal. However everytime I use that command, my laptop became very sluggish and practically unusable. From System Monitor, it appeared that compiz ate all of the available CPU power.

Then I tried two live CDs, Kubuntu 12.10 and Linux Mint Nadia (Cinnamon edition). The problem exists in Nadia and doesn't in Kubuntu. As Nadia Cinnamon uses compiz while Kubuntu does not compiz, it is another hint that compiz was the cause of the problem.

So, I installed `gnome-session-fallback` and log in again using Gnome Classic (with No effect) and the problem dissapeared.